# Get keys from nested Javascript Object based on some condition

Tags: javascript

i am having JSON `Object` in the form of

```js
{
  "detailObject": {
    "user": {
      "userProperty": {
        "active": {
          "id": "3be0d467",
          "value": null,
          "duration": "4 hrs"
        }
      },
      "userRegion": {
        "active": {
          "id": "3be0d467",
          "value": null,
          "duration": "5 hrs"
        }
      }
    },
    "OtherInfo": [
      {
        "year": {
          "active": {
            "id": "3be0d467",
            "value": null,
            "duration": ""
          }
        },
        "volume": {
          "active": {
             "id": "3be0d467",
             "value": null,
             "duration": ""
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now i want to map it in a single object like `{"userProperty":"4 hrs","userRegion":"5 hrs","year":"","volume":""}` i.e parent `key` and `duration`

or `[{"userProperty":"4 hrs"},{"userRegion":"5 hrs"},{"year":""},{"volume":""}]`

Comment: "Based on some condition". What condition might that be?
Or do you simply want to take one key from every object as you showed with duration?

Comment: @ThaekeHekkenberg just want  `parent name as key` and  `duration` as value

Comment: Do you always want to reduce an object with that interface to an object like `{"userProperty":"4 hrs","userRegion":"5 hrs","year":"","volume":""}`?

Comment: @JaredASutton yes either object or an array both will work for me see the updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the exhausive traverse through the data object:

- the base condition is to stop when a checked value is not an array and object
- if the value to check is an array, continue to traverse through each element
- if the value is an object, check if it contains the non-undefined path of `active.duration`, if the that condition is met, store the key and the value achieved from that path

```js
const res = []
const exhausiveTraverse = (data) => {
  if (isArray(data)) {
    data.map((el) => exhausiveTraverse(el))
  } else if (isObject(data)) {
    Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {
      if (getByPath(value, ["active", "duration"]) !== undefined) {
        res.push({ [key]: getByPath(value, ["active", "duration"]) })
      } else {
        exhausiveTraverse(value)
      }
    })
  } else {
    return undefined
  }
}
```

---

Full code

```js
const data = {
  detailObject: {
    user: {
      userProperty: {
        active: {
          id: "3be0d467",
          value: null,
          duration: "4 hrs",
        },
      },
      userRegion: {
        active: {
          id: "3be0d467",
          value: null,
          duration: "5 hrs",
        },
      },
    },
    OtherInfo: [
      {
        year: {
          active: {
            id: "3be0d467",
            value: null,
            duration: "",
          },
        },
        volume: {
          active: {
            id: "3be0d467",
            value: null,
            duration: "",
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
}

const isArray = (arr) => Array.isArray(arr)

const isObject = (obj) =>
  typeof obj === "object" && obj !== null && !Array.isArray(obj)

const getByPath = (obj, path) => {
  try {
    return path.reduce((acc, p) => acc[p], obj)
  } catch (err) {
    return undefined
  }
}

const res = []
const exhausiveTraverse = (data) => {
  if (isArray(data)) {
    data.map((el) => exhausiveTraverse(el))
  } else if (isObject(data)) {
    Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {
      if (getByPath(value, ["active", "duration"]) !== undefined) {
        res.push({ [key]: getByPath(value, ["active", "duration"]) })
      } else {
        exhausiveTraverse(value)
      }
    })
  } else {
    return undefined
  }
}

exhausiveTraverse(data)
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by looping through the object's properties.

**Note:** This assumes that your object will always look the way you described it above, where:

- `detailObject.user` is an object of sub-objects, where each sub-object has `subObject.active.duration`
- `detailObject.OtherInfo` is an array of one object, where the object has `object.active.duration`

In this example, I use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

```js
const myObject = {
  "detailObject": {
    "user": {
      "userProperty": {
        "active": {
          "id": "3be0d467",
          "value": null,
          "duration": "4 hrs"
        }
      },
      "userRegion": {
        "active": {
          "id": "3be0d467",
          "value": null,
          "duration": "5 hrs"
        }
      }
    },
    "OtherInfo": [
      {
        "year": {
          "active": {
            "id": "3be0d467",
            "value": null,
            "duration": ""
          }
        },
        "volume": {
          "active": {
             "id": "3be0d467",
             "value": null,
             "duration": ""
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};

const results = {};
for (const [userDataName, userData] of Object.entries(myObject.detailObject.user)) {
  results[userDataName] = userData.active.duration;
}
for (const [userDataName, userData] of Object.entries(myObject.detailObject.OtherInfo[0])) {
  results[userDataName] = userData.active.duration;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, '\t'));
```

Comment: `myObject.detailObject.user` for some other objects `detailObject` might be something else so this should be dynamic

Comment: What else might `detailObject` be?

Comment: We need to know the exact schema of this object, so that we can account for every possible structure.

Comment: For some cases it would might be `MissInfo` it is dynamic , so only this is consistent is the interface `{id,value,duration}`

Answer (score 0):

Since the object has different types of data, they must be converted to the same type. I use `flat` to move the array at `OtherInfo` to a higher level. Then collect a new object using `reduce`.

```js
const myObject = {
  "detailObject": {
    "user": {
      "userProperty": {
        "active": {
          "id": "3be0d467",
          "value": null,
          "duration": "4 hrs"
        }
      },
      "userRegion": {
        "active": {
          "id": "3be0d467",
          "value": null,
          "duration": "5 hrs"
        }
      }
    },
    "OtherInfo": [{
      "year": {
        "active": {
          "id": "3be0d467",
          "value": null,
          "duration": ""
        }
      },
      "volume": {
        "active": {
          "id": "3be0d467",
          "value": null,
          "duration": ""
        }
      }
    }]
  }
};

const result = Object.values(myObject.detailObject)
  .flat(Infinity)
  .reduce((obj, value) => (Object.entries(value).forEach(item => obj[item[0]] = item[1].active.duration), obj), {});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive approach will be helpful here. Use `Object.entries` and recursively check for "active" and "duration" keys.

```js
const recuriveAdd = (obj, res) => {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    obj.forEach((item) => recuriveAdd(item, res));
  } else {
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if ("active" in value) {
        res.push({ [key]: value.active.duration });
      } else {
        Object.values(value).forEach((item) => recuriveAdd(item, res));
      }
    });
  }
};

obj = {
  detailObject: {
    user: {
      userProperty: {
        active: {
          id: "3be0d467",
          value: null,
          duration: "4 hrs",
        },
      },
      userRegion: {
        active: {
          id: "3be0d467",
          value: null,
          duration: "5 hrs",
        },
      },
    },
    OtherInfo: [
      {
        year: {
          active: {
            id: "3be0d467",
            value: null,
            duration: "",
          },
        },
        volume: {
          active: {
            id: "3be0d467",
            value: null,
            duration: "",
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};

const res = [];
recuriveAdd(obj, res);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```js
const jsonObj = {
    "detailObject": {
        "user": {
            "userProperty": {
                "active": {
                    "id": "3be0d467",
                    "value": null,
                    "duration": "4 hrs"
                }
            },
            "userRegion": {
                "active": {
                    "id": "3be0d467",
                    "value": null,
                    "duration": "5 hrs"
                }
            }
        },
        "OtherInfo": [{
            "year": {
                "active": {
                    "id": "3be0d467",
                    "value": null,
                    "duration": ""
                }
            },
            "volume": {
                "active": {
                    "id": "3be0d467",
                    "value": null,
                    "duration": ""
                }
            }
        }]
    }
};

const {detailObject: {user}} = jsonObj;
const {detailObject: {OtherInfo: [other]}} = jsonObj;
const customObj = {...user, ...other};

const myObj = (
    ({
        userProperty: {active: {duration: propDur}},
        userRegion: {active: {duration: regDur}},
        year: {active: {duration: yearDur}},
        volume: {active: {duration: volDur}}
    }) => ({
        userProperty: propDur,
        userRegion: regDur,
        year: yearDur,
        volume: volDur
    })
)(customObj);

console.log(myObj);
```

I think the best solution should be using [destructuring of objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). I created **`myObj`**, the one that you need, using [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

Using my approach you can also declare a default value for a key, if not found in the **`jsonObj`**.